# Unlink synonyms on thinking sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, synonym

Im using thinking sphinx and libstemmer (pt-BR).
My problem is:
When I search "banheira" or "banheiras" sphinx gets the same results that matches with
"banheiro"/"banheiros".

Im trying to unlink the words "banheira" and "banheiro" because they are not the same
thing.
I didn't find any solution for this.
Anybody had the same problem?

Thanks!

Regards (:

Answer (score 1):

Copied from: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11946

Read the docs on wordforms:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

can be used to implement 'stemming exceptions' :)